# Whatsapp update and sharing video

Tags: ios, video, sharing, whatsapp, uidocumentinteraction

I am making an app that shares a video through whatsapp.
Implementation is super easy, and it worked well until the beginning of August. When you trigger WhatsApp with the DocumentInteractionController, the controller will propose 2 options for WhatsApp:(can't post a screenshot due to reputation...)

1. "WhatsApp"
2. "Open in WhatsApp"

"WhatsApp" will push a vc within your app, when "Open in WhatsApp" will put your app in background as usual and open WhatsApp. The problem is that the first option "WhatsApp" doesn't give any information in the delegate method of the DocumentInteractionController, I can't manage to detect if the user pressed the button or not, as well as when the sharing is done. Anyone encountered the issue?